# AngularJS: fire $watch only element value changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to fire $watch only element value is changed.

```
var obj = {
  elem1: 1,
  elem2: 2
};

$scope.a = obj;     // (1)

$scope.a.elem1 = 3; // (2)

$scope.$watch('a', function(e) {
  // Do something
}, true);
```

I would like to fire $watch only at `(2)`. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as passing the object's property in to $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('a.elem1', function(e) {
  // Do something
}, true);
```